# Target Blank Not Working?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, target, squarespace

I am trying to get the links I have routed to open in a new window using the "attr" feature in jQuery with no luck.

Here is the client site: http://www.sunsetstudiosent.com working in the "News" section.

Additionally is there a way to differentiate and apply this only to links that link offsite?

```
  <script>
     var sBlock = $('[data-block-json*="9dac9e62587eab820575"]'),
         items = sBlock.find('.summary-item');  
     $.each(items, function() { 
       var $this = $(this),
           itemLink = $this.find('.summary-title a').attr('href');
       $this.find('.summary-read-more-link').attr('href', itemLink);
       $this.find('.summary-metadata-item a').attr('href', itemLink);
       $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
     });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line of vanilla Javascript will do it for you; no jQuery needed:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#block-8c94657a90c2362b8126 .summary-title-link')
    .forEach(function(x) {
        x.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    });
```

Similar code that also checks if the link is on the same domain before applying `target="_blank"`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#block-8c94657a90c2362b8126 .summary-title-link')
    .forEach(function(x) {
        var url = new URL(x.href);
        if (url.host !== window.location.host) {
            x.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    });
```

You may want to wrap the function body in a try-catch block if you aren't certain the links on those elements will be added.

Comment: Thanks, this working great! Is there a way to differential only for links that navigate offsite using the domain as reference?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "differential"?

Comment: Sorry, meant differentiate.

Comment: Yeah that's what the if statement in the second code example does; it compares the location of the window (the domain) to the location of the link; if the hosts are not the same, then its offsite

Answer (score 0):

Because `$(this)` is holding `.summary-item` which not an anchor tag...

So `$(this).attr('target', '_blank')` will add the `target` attribute to the `.summary-item` not to its `<a>` tags...

So you will need to change the logic here...try to use `find()` jQuery here

```
$(this).find("a").attr('target', '_blank');
```

So your complete code will be

```
var sBlock = $('[data-block-json*="9dac9e62587eab820575"]'),
  items = sBlock.find('.summary-item');
$.each(items, function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    itemLink = $this.find('.summary-title a').attr('href');
  $this.find('.summary-read-more-link').attr('href', itemLink);
  $this.find('.summary-metadata-item a').attr('href', itemLink);
  $(this).find("a").attr('target', '_blank');
});
```